# JQuery attr() and Data() Returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question has already been asked but no answer solved my problem don't know why below is the image of my code +

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $('button').click(deletingTheCar);
}

function deletingTheCar() {
  // alert($(this).data('id'));
  var my = $(this).data('data-items');
  alert(my);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-items="yes got  it" id="osama">Hi</button>
```

[image: Screen shot of my code]

Comment: just change to `var my = $(this).attr('data-items');`  
but be sure that there is only a single `<button>` on that html

Comment: @CalvinNunes or, even better, change it to `var my = $(this).data('items');`

Comment: yeah, that's a good choice too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to get `data-* attributes` the best method is **[`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)**, and the `.data()` doesn't need the first part `data-` to be passed as parameter, so just replace :

```
$(this).data('data-items');
______________^^^^ //You have extra 'data' here
```

By :

```
$(this).data('items');
```

**Working sample:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $('button').click(deletingTheCar);
}

function deletingTheCar() {
  console.log( $(this).data('items') );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-items="yes got it" id="osama">Hi</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Update `var my = $(this).data('data-items');` to

`var my = $(this).data('items');`

Comment: .attr also returns undefined but when i used var my = $(this).data('items');  it worked

Comment: @OsamaInayat if accessing something that was created on page load, both `data('items')` and `attr('data-items')` should return the same thing.